# Plotting graph on nodes

Tags: python

I have a set of clusters and have extracted the centroid coordinates of each clusters and plot it on a scatter graph. Here are the coordinates:

```
112 59
214 90
244 182
254 167
255 112
261 139
283 152
291 134
314 138
334 49
333 34
```

And the following is the code to plot the scatter graph:

```
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt('centroid_coordinates.txt')
pl.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1])
pl.xlabel('x-coordinate')
pl.ylabel('y-coordinate')


#print result
plt.title('Centroids')
pl.show()
```

...which results in the following:
[image]

And now I would like to join the centroid nodes together to form a graph to show its spatial conenctivity relationship. Any suggestions to do that?

Comment: You could use the Python package [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html) to build graphs and display them.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`networkx` is your friend:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import itertools

nodes = [[112, 59],
[214, 90],
[244, 182],
[254, 167],
[255, 112],
[261, 139],
[283, 152],
[291, 134],
[314, 138],
[334, 49],
[333, 34]]

# initialise empty graph
G = nx.Graph()

# create dictionary for node positions
positions={}
for node, properties in enumerate(nodes):
    positions[node] = properties

# add the nodes to the graph
G.add_nodes_from(positions.keys())

# list all possible combinations of nodes within the graph    
edges = itertools.product(positions.keys(), positions.keys())

# and add them to the graph
G.add_edges_from(edges)

# draw nodes and edges, positioned at the centroids
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=positions)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=positions)
```

Comment: Just a quick question. Is there a way to not list all the combinations? Just a simple connected graph would be fine since some of the graphs have too many nodes and the graph just gets too crowded. Cheers!

Comment: check out the documentation of [nx.draw_networkx_edges](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html). you can pass an additional parameter, `edgelist`, that allows you to specify which ones you want to be shown.